# Faster page processing with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

So far I have a working code that use `HtmlUnit` to get a page `asXML`

However, I find it that, it is processing everything on the page including shockwave flash objects. Which makes the processing slow.

I just need it to process, the plain HTML and Javascript, so that it will be faster.

This is my code:

```
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(sb.toString());
        webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().pumpEventLoop(PUMP_TIME);
        pageString = page.asXml();
```

`page.asXml()` is quite slow, maybe because of the points I stated above?

Is there a way to tell HtmlUnit not to process unecessary parts of the page?

This is where I see that the page processing stuck up for quite some time (many times):

```
[INFO] SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.] sourceName=[http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_ads_gpt.js] line=[9] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

- Also does HtmlUnit loads css and images too in memory?

Comment: Anyone can suggest any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlUnit can't process flash. It does take a lot of time to process JS, though. Probably, the JS is getting something from the net and that is also taking more time. Anyway, note that the log is actually an `INFO` and not a `SEVERE` and basically it is telling you that it is not creating any flash object.

I would recommend you to avoid the processing of JS, if possible.

Comment: Ok, how to I turn off the processing of JS, by not calling 'getJavaScriptEngine()'? Or there's a correct way. I will try to turn if off, however, usually in Ajax apps, javascript is the one that builds the DOM for dynamic contents.

Comment: To disable JS you should use `webClient.getOptions().setJavascriptEnabled(false)`. Anyway, HtmlUnit is not usually very helpful when handling AJAX. Just check this [FAQ](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork) and suffer :)

Comment: Really not good with Ajax? Hmm... I learned about HtmlUnit as many suggest to use it for Ajax crawling.

Comment: Also, I did disabled javascript, but still its processing so much thing. Is there a configuration that will ensure that HtmlUnit will just process html?