# Using HtmlUnit produces a long list of errors

Tags: java, htmlunit

What I am trying to do is go to a website, select items from two drop down lists, type something into a box, and then press a button. I then want to get the resulted text that will be in a box that you can't type in.

The site I want to use is http://www.worldlingo.com/en/products_services/worldlingo_translator.html and here is my code that does everything I'm trying to do except getting the final text (as I don't know how to do that yet).

```
try {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Page page = webClient.getPage("http://www.worldlingo.com/en/products_services/worldlingo_translator.html");

        HtmlSelect select = ((HtmlSelect) page).getElementById("SelSrcLang");
        HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue("English");
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        HtmlSelect select2 = ((HtmlSelect) page).getElementById("SelTrgLang");
        HtmlOption option2 = select2.getOptionByValue("French");
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option2, true);

        final HtmlForm form = ((HtmlPage) page).getFormByName("form");         
        final HtmlSubmitInput button =  form.getInputByName("Translate");
        final HtmlTextInput textField =  form.getInputByName("wl_ft_print_text");        
        textField.setValueAttribute("How are you?");

        page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Translate").click();

        System.out.println("Finished");

    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) { } catch (MalformedURLException e) { } catch (IOException e) { }
```

EDIT: After changing

```
Page page = webCLient...
```

to

```
HtmlPage page = webCLient...
```

I get no errors but when I run I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[option] attributeName=[value] attributeValue=[English]
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect.getOptionByValue(HtmlSelect.java:437)
>       at maple.Main.main(Main.java:43)

Line 43 is

```
HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue("English");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

80% of the "errors" you're talking about are actually warnings. Those are mostly JavaScript unconformities that you might probably disregard (or correct in the server if you actually have access to the code, which I guess you don't as it seems you're webscraping the page).

19% of the actual errors are related to Flash objects not being able to be created. This makes sense, as HtmlUnit can't handle flash. Check this other similar question: [Faster page processing with HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644502). Anyway, you should also disregard those errors as they should actually be informational messages.

1% is the actual error that is not allowing you run your code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage cannot be cast to 
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect
    at maple.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

Altough I can't tell which is line 42 I bet it is this one:

```
HtmlSelect select = ((HtmlSelect) page).getElementById("SelSrcLang");
```

There you have an `HtmlPage` object and you are casting it to an `HtmlSelect`. That would produce the exception above. Probably you were trying to do this:

```
HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("SelSrcLang");
```

Note this will only work if you use an `HtmlPage` not a `Page` object. See [JavaDoc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getHtmlElementById%28java.lang.String%29).

I hope this remote debugging session has helped :)

Comment: When I change the line (which in fact is line 42) it tells me that it's an error "The method getElementById(String) is undefined for the type Page" and the solution is to "Add Parentheses around the cast".

Comment: Whatever IDE you're using (Eclipse I guess) is doing its best to guess the error. However, they are not right all the time. That error becomes evident when reading the JavaDoc. I've updated the answer.

Comment: So does that mean I can't use that page or is there another way to do it?

Comment: It means you have to add 4 letters to the code: replace `Page` with `HtmlPage`. Actually, you're already using an `HtmlPage` instance (take a look at the exception) but as your variable is of class `Page` you're getting compile time errors

Comment: After changing that, it's telling me it can't find "English" when it is an option. I've updated the OP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36347/discussion-between-user2612619-and-mosty-mostacho)